# Is it possible to get a PhD grant in Europe/US with the research focused on Kazakhstan?

Tags: phd

I am from Kazakhstan. Currently, I am a 2 year MA student in Eurasian Studies in Kazakhstan. The topic of my research is ethnic Kazakhs' integration in Kazakhstan. I like to investigate problems of ethnic migrants' integration in Kazakhstan. In particular, Kazakhs who have born in neighbouring countries and after decided to migrate to Kazakhstan, their ancestral homeland.

I wish to go further to PhD program in Europe/US, programs linked to migration. Is it possible to get the grant/scholarship abroad with the research concentrated on Kazakhstan? or I should choose another topic of study?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I think your chance would be higher with professors focusing on a specific area geographically and also check professors being interested in migration or integration. I think it is not impossible. Just develop a proposal. If it does not work, change your focus.
I am not sure about a scholarship or grant. They are highly competitive. Good luck with it.